# "Вечная память"

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Вечная память павшим" или "вечная память о павших"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе оба варианта возможны, но с несколько разным смыслом.
При обращении к умершим принято "вечная память (тебе/Вам)". "Вечная память павшим" я рассматриваю как некое стяжение полной формы "Павшие, вечная память вам" - и таким образом, естественно, допускаю не только её нормативность но и предпочтительность в соответвующих случаях. 
Вне такого контекста можно сказать и "Вечная память о них (останется в наших сердцах)".